# C++ finding the min location, sort, and swap in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, 2d, swap

Ok sorry for asking this question if it has already been answered before but I just couldn't find it due to that there formatting was completely different from mine or that they used a different method than the one I'm currently being taught. They all have to be in separate functions and I haven't been taught vectors or pointers. I've seen some questions that have been answered that way but its a little advance in the class for now.

My most pressing question is when trying to get the location of the min. number within a 2D array. Do I have to do some type of braces or something in order for it to scan the entire array. An example would be: location = index, J; or location = Array[index][J];

Or do I have to do something else within the if statement?

Apologies if my code formatting is not correct for the post.

```
  int MinLocation(int Array[][COL], int Row, int COl, int s)`
  {
     int min = max;
    int location = 0;

    for (int index = s; index < Row; index++)
     {
         for (int J = s; J < COL; J++)
         {


           if (Array[index][COL] < min)
           {
               min = Array[index][J];
               location = J;
           }

        }

     }
   return location;
 }



   void Sort(int Array[][COL], int Rows, int COL)
   {

     int Min;
     int MinSpot;
     int current;
     int currentLocation;
     int start;

     for (int index = 0; index < Rows; index++)
     {

        for (int J = 0; J < COL; J++)
        {
          start = index;//Starts at O on the array

          current = Array[index][J];

          currentLocation = index;

          Min = FindMIN(Array, Rows, COL, start);

          MinSpot = MinLocation(Array, Rows, COL, start);

         Swap(Array, currentLocation, MinSpot);

       }

     }
   }
   void Swap(int Array[][COL], int& x, int& y)
   {

     int first, second;


    first = Array[x][COL];
    second = Array[y][COL];


    Array[x][COL] = second;
    Array[y][COL] = first;

   }
```

Comment: Do you know how to find the minimum in a simple array (1D)?

Comment: Yes I was able to get it to work on a 1D array. Would u like me to post that as well?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know how much I had to explain.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate over a (so-called) 2D array is to use two nested loops:

```
for(unsigned int j=0; j<numRows; ++j)
  for(unsigned int k=0; k<numColumns; ++k)
    ... do something with A[j][k] ...
```

Comment: But I thought that I was doing that with my two for loops. Also are you saying that I should put in a do/while loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find minimum in particular column, then you don't need nested loop... But if you want to find minimum from whole array, then you need nested loops.
And In your code... All you wanna do is selecting one element from array and swap it with the minimum value element of array.

But you are not changing the COL index of array in if statement. That means you are finding minimum element in just one column.

Comment: Do you mean something like in my if statement? I think I was able to find the location in it.                                           `min = Array[index][COL];`

Comment: Well I tried to understand what you meant and I put in another if statement. `if (Array[index][COL] < min)
   {
    min = Array[index][COL];
    location = index;
   }` It seems like it works ok, is this what you meant by not changing the COL.

Comment: firstly... tell me you wanna sort only one column of array or the whole array?

Comment: Well that's later but I do want to sort the whole array.

Comment: then you need to find the minimum element from the whole array... but in your function minlocation, your loop are traversing only a part of array, (s,s) to (ROW, COL) and in if statement, array[index][col]<min means you are checking just one column of array.  It should be array[index][J]<min

Comment: That worked, it now says the correct column.  Now I just need to figure out the sort and swap functions since there giving me errors. Thank you very much for the help!